# URL containing jquery accesible through browser but fails when accessed by curl

Tags: python, json, curl

I want to read the information accessible through [this](https://www.flukso.net/api/sensor/fed676021dacaaf6a12a8dda7685be34?callback=jQuery17102322320200116248_1393236774623&version=1.0&interval=week&resolution=15min&unit=kwhperyear&_=1393237427662) URL. This gives the appropriate data using any browser but throws a bad request error when trying to access using curl:

```
curl -k -v -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -H "X-Version: 1.0" \
  "https://www.flukso.net/api/sensor/fed676021dacaaf6a12a8dda7685be34?callback=jQuery17102322320200116248_1393236774623&version=1.0&interval=week&resolution=15min&unit=kwhperyear&_=1393237427662"
```

How can I access this information using curl or python?

Answer (score 0):

The Url you have given at the description is expired I think. It gets me `400 Bad request` from browser or from commandline.

There are few servers around which use to return such error when there is no User-Agent string is provided with request parameters. So try adding with a Useragent:

```
-A "Mozilla 5/0"
```

Another reason can be the proper authentication or something like that. May be you are missing that!